# How would I break this project up

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a project which is a single solution in VS2010, and I wanted to have it such that:

- Solution one: Admin
- Solution Two: Front end
- Solution three: Models

The reason for this is that Admin will sit in it's own app pool and the front end will sit in another app pool. We then have model talk to both and under model is the SQL database.

my question is:

How do I set this up in to three separate projects such that models can talk to Admin, Front end and the database?

Comment: You have few choices : web services, they talk to one db, so there is no problem. You want more?

Comment: im looking for a detailed tutorial on how to set up a project like this as I am new to ASP.net. @IamStalker

Comment: @TheWebs Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, can't you just add a project reference? Create three different projects, then add a reference to the `Models` project in both `Admin` and `FrontEnd`.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking but then I thought, if I log in as admin, make a change to some record, lets say, for example, I add a new location. will the front end see that? or do I have to reference admin in front end?

Comment: @TheWebs That all depends on how your application is wired up. If you have classes or any code you've written in `Admin` that you would like the `FrontEnd` to be aware of or utilize, you need to add it as a project reference. The communication between the two does not happen automatically - you need to build the interaction layer.

Comment: Is there any tutorials on this? because what I was thinking is that I could do `Admin -> Models -> Database <- Pull From and View -> Front end`

Answer (score 0):

For what you describe I think you'd be better off keeping one Solution and having multiple projects under it.

You can deploy the results of building the Admin project to one web site and the results of building the Front End project to another web site.

Each of these would reference the Models project.  Models don't normally 'talk to' other projects but are referenced by them because the initiating action is coming from a web page request to either site - that's what's controlling the flow.

Often you'd also have another project which is a background service which may also reference your models project.  This project would run as an NT Service providing time-based execution of work items that aren't tied to an incoming web request, for example, sending emails.

A further level of complexity would be to introduce a services layer and Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).  You background service and all web sites now call into the services layer and interact only with DTOs while the service layer uses model objects to communicate with the database.  You can now evolve your database schema independently from your web applications provided the service contract remains the same.

Comment: I would suggest a more detailed explain. With a fully detailed class structure. Do that and you have my vote.